# Using MDC or Threadlocal

Tags: java, dropwizard, thread-local, mdc

I'd like to propagate `X-Request-Id` received from my Nginx to other services in my k8s when calling them using http.

Right now, I'm using request filters to catch that `X-Request-Id` header and putting it to the MDC.

```java
        final String nginxRequestId = requestContext.getHeaderString("X-Request-Id");
        if (nginxRequestId != null) {
            MDC.put("infra_request", nginxRequestId);
        }
```

Now, I'm calling the endpoint of service B inside the k8s (so no Nginx in the way) and I'd like to obtain that `X-Request-Id` to put it into the request's header. I can see two options here:

1. simply get that value from MDC
2. store that header in the thread local variable (as the service is using Dropwizard) in addition to storing it in MDC

I'd probably do it using the MDC, but I'm not sure whether this is the best practice or whether there could be some catch/problems with that.

Comment: Since `MDC` uses `ThreadLocal`, what advantage would you get from an *additional* `ThreadLocal`? Just make sure you clean up your `MDC` afterwards.

Comment: I mean, the MDC is primary used for logging so I wasn't sure whether this would always work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for your purpose it is good to use MDC. Internally MDC uses ThreadLocal. Even if you use ThreadLocal, for a nicer way of implementation you will wrap ThreadLocal variable in a class. MDC does the same for you.

Comment: But that comes with a caveat that if your code logs all MDC data than now this additional data will also get logged which might or might not be okay/required depending upon use case, for example in my case it wasn't

Answer (score 5):

I have used both the MDC and ThreadLocal for the similar purpose of passing a transaction-id to the headers. Internally, MDC uses ThreadLocal and it has some predefined functionalities like adding a prefix to every log. I would suggest having ThreadLocal if the data which you are putting is of some business use, otherwise, you can go with MDC.

Comment: Exactly this is my current approach - to use MDC just for logging purposes, but now I'd like to read from it outside of the logging - so it has kind fo business use and thus I'm thinking about using thread local instead. However, I'm not sure whether this is overengineering or just better...

Comment: I don't see any problem with your approach.